# .NET MVC deploy issue - "It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm getting errors with a MVC web application which deployed to a host provider.

**1) About the application**

I had problems with deploying more complex applications also, but to make sure, I have created a simple application. Every info I will provide here will be about that simple application.

a) How did application created?

- The application is a very simple .NET MVC Web Application created just for deploying test.
- The application created with Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web, as ASP.NET MVC 4 Web application, and uses .NET Framework 4.
- The application created on 'Basic' project template, then I added just one controller, and one view. That's all.
- There's nothing else in the view than a header which says *TESTING PAGE*.

b) How did application deployed?

I used only FTP technique, with two tools.

- I deployed the application manually with using FileZilla.

  - I get reference from an article about which files to upload. And also then confirmed the file list was matching with files uploaded with Visual Studio 2012, which I described below.
- I deployed the application using Visual Studio 2012;

  - With using built-in Publish action,
  - Created new publish profile
  - Used FTP publish method,
  - No errors occurred. All succeed. And confirmed that directory has created and files has copied to server.

**2) About the Host**

Host I used is bought from an ordinary hosting provider.

- It says it supports Asp / Asp.Net / Php5
- There's nothing on my control panel except links to sections of: other packages hosting company provides, domains, my password and my personal info.
- There's an ASP.NET website running on same host without any problem.
- I'm trying to upload to a sub directory of an existing html website. e.g. www.example.com/theApplication
- On the error I see, version information looks like this;

> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

**3) About the Problem**

When I browse the directory I have published the application to, I see an error message;

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

(Error is on line 24)

```
Line 22: <customErrors mode="Off"/>
Line 23:    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
Line 24:     <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 25:       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
Line 26:     </authentication>
```

- And below that, error correctly points to root web.config file of the application.
- And there's another 4 errors printed under *'Show Additional Configuration Errors:'* title at the bottom, pointing to 4 different lines on the same web.config file. They are like this one;

  > It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. (C:\webroot\site.com\wwwroot\test\web.config line XX)

  - Lines on the web.config file that errors points to;

(All inside  xml tags)

```
  profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider"
  membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider"
  roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider"
  sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider"
```

**4) What I have tried so far?**

I'm an absolute beginner on .NET platform. So I cannot think of a possible cause or possible action.
Still, I have looked into many articles for two days, but cannot find anything useful. Google suffocates my searches with articles which all describes the solution of the same problem, but for hosting to local server. I could not found anything for this particular issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem:

**I'm trying to upload to a sub directory of an existing html website**

It sounds like you haven't setup this subdirectory as it's own application in IIS, which would cause you to see this error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I understand: If I put this in root directory, the error will gone(?) Secondly, Should I use IIS on my own machine, to access to the server machine and set that sub-directory as application?

Comment: @Lazysheepherd That's correct, if you put this in the root web.config, the error will go away, but forms authentication will then apply to your entire application, which may not be what you want.  You should be able to set your subfolder as it's own application using your hosting company's control panel.

Comment: That worked. I moved my files to root and worked without problems.